# How can i handle online status in pjsip in iphone

Tags: iphone, pjsip

We are developing an application in that we are providing VOIP feature using pjsip.We done every thing well upto registration process and adding friends .But We are facing some problems regarding to friends online status.

I explain my problem indetail..For suppose 'user1' is login  and has one friend 'user2' then user2 is offline it is correct(b'coz user2 still not login) when user2 login and has one friend user1 then user1 is online it is correct(b'coz user1 already logedin) but user2 is not shown online in user1's friends

can any one solve my problem ,i stuck here for last 3 days. thanks inadvance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple exercise using PJSUA app which should help you solve your problem

1. Start PJSUA app (on default port). Call this pjsua-app1.
2. Start another instance of PJSUA on another port. Call this pjsua-app2.
3. To pjsua-app1 add account user1@a.b.c.d:p, to pjsua-app2 add account user2@a.b.c.d:q
4. To pjsua-app1 add buddy user2 and to pjsua-app2 add buddy user1
5. On both apps subscribe presence.
6. You should see them online if they are logged in